# Google Analytics not reporting

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I have an Android app that used Google Analytics v2 for a year and has worked well. I recently upgraded it to version 4 by removing the old .jar library and adding Google Play Services as a project dependency. The app compiles and everything seems to be working, however no data is being sent to Google Analytics (I already have over 1000 users that upgraded to the newer version but all I see are hits made by the older version).

Here's the relevant code:

App.java (Application class)

```
public class App extends Application {

    private Tracker mTracker = null;

    /**
     * Get the current Google Analytics tracker instance
     * @return The Google Analytics tracker instance
     */
    public synchronized Tracker getTracker() {
        if(mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.analytics);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<resources>
  <!--Google Analytics tracking ID -->
  <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-Y</string>

  <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

  <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
  <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

When I start the app, I simply call getApplication().getTracker() to initialize the tracker, and since the automatic activity tracking is turned on it should work to my best understanding.

Why am I not seeing any reports from the v4 app while the v2 is still able to send data?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having problems with this and it turned out to be the Google Play library version. In the android manifest, there should be a line like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Then I had problems because the newest play version wasn't available on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus with android 4.3 (*W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(8231): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5208000 but found 5089036*). I then tried using the older version in Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

But at the end, I still had problems with it working (you can usually see the error messages in the log, they will have your app's package name in the tag, something like this: *E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.*) so I just got back to v3, which you can find as a separate jar, and everything works.